# Add custom holidays in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, fscalendar

I am using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and its displaying only default holidays like on Sunday (The weekend) and so I want to add my own holidays in it and change color.
So please anyone knows how to add custom holidays????

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to maintain holidays list on code level like model class(Array) or you can use the database for storing holidays list. At the render time only adopt the *FSCalendarDelegateAppearance* delegate. This call a delegate function for every date.

See example i think it can help you,

```
var datesWithHolidays = ["2018/09/03", "2018/10/06", "2018/09/12", "2018/10/25"]

//This is the delegate method
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

    let dateString = self.dateFormatter1.string(from: date)
    if self.datesWithHolidays.contains(dateString) {
        return UIColor.green
    }
    return nil

}
```